# mapreduce wroking on single node cluster but not on multinode cluster

Tags: hadoop

I am running a map reduce program which works fine on my cdh quickstart vm but when trying on a multinode cluster, it gives the below error:

```
WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications         should implement Tool for the same.
14/02/12 00:23:06 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be     found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
14/02/12 00:23:06 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/02/12 00:23:07 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201401221117_5777
14/02/12 00:23:08 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/02/12 00:23:16 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201401221117_5777_m_000000_0,     Status : FAILED
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class Mappercsv not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1774)
    at     org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:631)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at    org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class Mappercsv not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1680)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1772)
    ... 8 more"
```

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question by me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781120/why-hadoop-does-not-know-my-map-class)

Comment: may be. If u faced the same issue, can u plz tell how did u solve it?

Comment: Did you click on the link above? Cause if you did, you would see how I solved the problem ;)

Comment: But I am not using Eclipse. Can u tell how to do it from terminal.

Comment: Well, I couldn't find the equivalent method for terminal. You can ask it in another question and I'm sure you will get your answer.

Comment: Could you please show us your code?

Comment: I dont know what was going wrong but i extracted the jar for the MR code from eclipse for single node cluster and used it in multinode cluster, it worked. may be in multinode some jar was missing or was present with some other name. i extracted the complete jar and ran it in multinode cluster.

Comment: ok i solved it. There were some jars which were named differently in multinode cluster. So i imported the required jars from my single node cluster and used them in classpath while compiling my code in multinode cluster