# Is jar creation necessary to execute MR on a remote cluster

Tags: hadoop, spring-data, spring-4, spring-data-hadoop

I have been trying Spring Data for Hadoop to execute a MR job from my local Windows STS on a remote Hadoop cluster.

The issue I face is mentioned in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396151/classnotfoundexception-after-job-submission)

There's a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236305/launch-a-mapreduce-job-from-eclipse) that has forced me to ask the below question.

**Is it necessary to first create a .jar file on my local windows machine(within the Eclipse/STS project's lib etc.) before it can be executed on a remote Hadoop cluster? Can't Spring Data simply push my code onto the remote cluster and trigger the execution?**